# Multiple click on submit button it's submit same form multiple time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was work in one codeigniter project, this project have large amount of data, i have one issue in data insert time click multiple time submit button it insert same data multiple time in database.

how it can possible ..?

Comment: After one click you can disable this button using Jquery like ```$('button').attr('disabled', "disabled")```

Comment: Are you insert data using Ajax request?

Comment: I am not use ajax for insert data .

Comment: yes I try to disable button on form submit and it work but i don't understand this issue codeigniter or php..

Comment: After click button page is redirect another page?

Comment: yes after submit page redirect another page .

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do this server-side.

Once the method in your controller or the script has been called, set a session variable stating that the form has been submitted.

For example,

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['formclicked'])) {
$_SESSION['formclicked'] = true; 
//now process form 

}

?>
```

This so the attacker won't be able to bypass client-side validation